# Oracle Function from Java

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am trying to call an Oracle function from my Java code something like this :

`Java`

```
CallableStatement cstmt = p_con.prepareCall("{? = CALL FXRATE_ENTITY(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}");
         cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);

         cstmt.setString(2, "SCR");
         cstmt.setString(3,l_srccur);
         cstmt.setString(4, l_tfcurr);
         cstmt.setString(5, "B001");

         cstmt.execute();
       String res = cstmt.getString(1);
```

but i am getting an exception

`java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 6`

for which i am not sure what i am doing wrong.Also this is the function I am trying to call

`Oracle Function`

```
FUNCTION FXRATE_ENTITY(CODCURRBASE IN VARCHAR, LCODCURRFROM IN VARCHAR, LCODCURRTO IN VARCHAR, LIDENTITY IN VARCHAR)
  RETURN NUMBER IS
  CODCUR_L VARCHAR2(3);
BEGIN
  IF (LCODCURRTO = '*') THEN
    RETURN NVL(FXRATE(CODCURRBASE, LCODCURRFROM, CODCURRBASE, LIDENTITY),
               0);
  ELSE
    RETURN NVL(FXRATE(CODCURRBASE, LCODCURRFROM, LCODCURRTO, LIDENTITY), 0);
  END IF;
END;
```

Any help or suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure prepared statements don't support any database specific sql functions/keywords. You'll probably need to use a native query for such things.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `?` in the prepare call statement which is not required as the first parameter is considered as the return parameter, so registering the out parameter using `registerOutParameter` is what we need.

Change the statement to below and it should work,

```
CallableStatement cstmt = p_con.prepareCall("{? = CALL FXRATE_ENTITY(?, ?, ?, ?)}");
```

Comment: Okay i removed the extra ```?``` but now i am getting ```Malformed SQL92 string at position: 5. Expecting "call" ``` as an exception.

Comment: Is it a standalone function or a package function ?

Comment: I am not sure but i think its a package function...

Comment: I have replicated the exact scenario and its working for me. Could you update the code ? and also mention assignment for `l_srccur` and `l_tfcurr`. last does the function you see in database starts with `create or replace` ? because calling a function inside package is different.

Comment: ```l_srccur``` and ```l_tfcurr``` are of ```String```type. No it doesn't starts with ```create or replace``` but its inside a package name ```Function``` where there are other functions too...

Comment: OK then change the statement to  add the package name as prefix. e.g `package_name.FXRATE_ENTITY.......`

Comment: like `CallableStatement cstmt = con.prepareCall("{? = call test_pkg.some_test(?, ?, ?, ?)}");`

Comment: Could you call the function in oracle client tool and see what is the output ? and also please show the package too ?